# JPA fetch from multiple tables to single POJO with named query

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, named-query

I have been trying to fetch data from 2 different tables to a single entity in JPA but with no result.

The entity that keeps data from two different tables is as below :

```
@Data @Entity @JsonSnakeCase

public class WareHouse {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private long id;

  @Column(unique = true)
  private String fcId;

  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private FCStatus status;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "fcId")
  private List<WorkingHours> workingHours;

  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private IntegrationType integrationType;
}
```

The other entity `WorkingHours` is :

```
@Data
@Entity
@JsonSnakeCase
public class WorkingHours {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    private String fcId;
    private LocalDate date;
    private DateTime start;
    private DateTime end;
}
```

The tables `WareHouse` and `WorkingHours` have one-to-many relationship and `fcId` is the column that joins them.

In my use case, I have to fetch `WareHouse` details and its `WorkingHours` in a single entity `WareHouse` as defined above. How do I achieve this ?

The named query (below) only fetches the `WareHouse` data and `WorkingHours` is coming empty. Is the data model wrong ? Or is the query wrong ? (I thought JPA would take care of automatically fetching from the related table when given the annotations `OneToMany` and `FetchType` etc.)

```
<named-query name="searchByFcId">
        <query>
            <![CDATA[
            select f from WareHouse f where f.fcId = :fc_id
            ]]>
        </query>
    </named-query>
```

Comment: looks alright, but maybe it is getting confused as you have fcId in both the `Warehouse` entity and the `WorkingHours` entity, so I guess that the real mapping column is not fcId.  Check you real DB to see what the FK is.

Comment: fcID is the foreign key in the DB.

Comment: but the PK of Warehouse is not the field that is referencing it is it?

Comment: Yes. the referenced column is not PK but a unique constrained column.

Comment: Sorry I am not communicating well.  If you look at your Warehouse table, what is the column name that references the WorkingHours ?

Comment: In the WareHouse table no relation is defined in the DB. But in the WorkingHours table fcId references fcId of WareHouse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following mappings. The JPA 2.0 spec note (11.1.21) notes:

```
If the referencedColumnName element is missing, the foreign key is assumed to 
refer to the primary key of the referenced table.
```

However it also goes on to note that:

```
Support for referenced columns that are not primary key columns of the 
referenced table is optional. Applications that use such mappings 
will not be portable.
```

So whether or not this works will depend on your provider.

Warehouse:

```
@Data 
@Entity 
@JsonSnakeCase
public class WareHouse {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private long id;

  @Column(unique = true)
  private String fcId;

  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private FCStatus status;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "warehouse", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private List<WorkingHours> workingHours;

  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private IntegrationType integrationType;
}
```

WorkingHours:

```
@Data
@Entity
@JsonSnakeCase
public class WorkingHours {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fcId", referencedColumnName="fcid")
    private Warehouse warehouse;

    private LocalDate date;
    private DateTime start;
    private DateTime end;
}
```

Comment: Yes. This solved it. Later I had to annotate jadira time types for date types to avoid serialization errors, and then I had to do JsonIgnoreProperties for the referenced objects to avoid infinite loops. But yes, this solved the original problem I had asked. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, good. There is actually no need to make the relationship  bidirectional (causing infinite loops). Removing the mapping of WorkingHour > Warehouse, moving the '@JoinColumn' annotation to the '@OneToMany' in Warehouse and removing the mappedBy would fix this issue and everything should still work as expected.

Comment: Interesting. I will try that.